# Is it possible to hide this file name using htaccess?

Tags: javascript, html, .htaccess

I have an HTML file that uses a script to "talk" to some actionscript. The script gets the "username" from the URL and tells the actionscript what to load. The problem I'm having is I can't the HTML file name to be invisible in the URL.

I want it to look like this: http://jawapa.bl.ee/ee/profiles/?/username

But, this is what it looks like now: http://jawapa.bl.ee/ee/profiles/index.html?/jawapa

I have tried a few things already, and none of them worked. One of them actually through a bunch of errors, and I couldn't get the site to load at all (kept giving a 500 error).

The script I'm using:

`var load_user = location.search.substring(2)`

I already have something in place to get rid of the .html file extention, but that doesn't work on this either...

I would like to avoid PHP, mainly because I know it can be done without it; just don't know how to :/

Comment: In most cases, one or more file names can be set as 'default document names'. If you set `index.html` as one of those default names, the url should work with or without the filename in it. Actually, your host should already have `index.html` set as a default document, according to their 'kennisbank', so I think you already made an error somewhere, causing this to fail.

Comment: I'm thinking you're right, because nothing is working. I'll go back and look at all the code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is.

But why you want to replace file name with a question mark?

Edit: Just realized your app is not a php or other language. I don't know this will work or not, but give it a try.

just show like:

profiles/username

To do:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^ee/profiles/(.*)$ ee/profiles/index.html/$1 [L]
```

Comment: When I try this, it gives me a 404 error and doesn't load the CSS

Answer (score 0):

Here is an htaccess snippet that might help you.

Rename your file to something unique like profile_usernames.html

**Then add this:**

`<Files "profile_usernames.html">
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all
</Files>`